# Airflow, FastAPI and postgres: host with docker

Tags: docker, airflow

I try to host different services together using docker. For that, I want to write files `docker-compose.yml` and `Dockerfile`. They follow below:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:latest
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
      POSTGRES_DB: ${POSTGRES_DB}
    ports:
      - "${POSTGRES_PORT}:${POSTGRES_PORT}"
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    ports:
      - "${REDIS_PORT}:${REDIS_PORT}"

  backend-app:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    environment:
      DATABASE_URL: postgres://${POSTGRES_USER}:${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}@postgres:${POSTGRES_PORT}/${POSTGRES_DB}

  airflow-scheduler:
    image: apache/airflow:latest
    command: scheduler
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - backend-app
    environment:
      - AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN=${AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN}
      - AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTOR=CeleryExecutor
      - AIRFLOW__CORE__CELERY_BROKER_URL=redis://${REDIS_PORT}
      - AIRFLOW__CORE__CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND=redis://${REDIS_PORT}
      - AIRFLOW__WEBSERVER__RBAC=${AIRFLOW__WEBSERVER__RBAC}
      - AIRFLOW__SCHEDULER__DAG_DIR_LIST_INTERVAL=${AIRFLOW__SCHEDULER__DAG_DIR_LIST_INTERVAL}
    volumes:
      - ./dags:/opt/airflow/dags
      - ./logs:/opt/airflow/logs
      - ./plugins:/opt/airflow/plugins
      
  airflow-webserver:
    image: apache/airflow:latest
    command: webserver
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - backend-app
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    environment:
      - AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN=${AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN}
      - AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTOR=CeleryExecutor
      - AIRFLOW__CORE__CELERY_BROKER_URL=redis://${REDIS_PORT}
      - AIRFLOW__CORE__CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND=redis://${REDIS_PORT}
      - AIRFLOW__WEBSERVER__RBAC=${AIRFLOW__WEBSERVER__RBAC}
      - AIRFLOW__SCHEDULER__DAG_DIR_LIST_INTERVAL=${AIRFLOW__SCHEDULER__DAG_DIR_LIST_INTERVAL}
    volumes:
      - ./dags:/opt/airflow/dags
      - ./logs:/opt/airflow/logs
      - ./plugins:/opt/airflow/plugins

networks:
  mynetwork:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

```
# Use the official Python image
FROM python:3.9 

# Set the working directory in the container
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the dependencies file to the working directory
COPY requirements_dev.txt .

# Install any dependencies
RUN pip install -r requirements_dev.txt

# Copy the rest of the application code
COPY . .

# Set up permissions for the log directory
RUN chown -R /opt/airflow/logs/scheduler
RUN mkdir -p /opt/airflow/logs/scheduler \
    && chown -R airflow:airflow /opt/airflow/logs

# Command to run the API
CMD ["uvicorn", "app.main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8000"]
```

After using these files above, the command run `docker-compose up` on the same folder as desired was succesful to host the postgres and redis databases as well as backend app, but not the airflow schedulers. Do you know why? I do not.

```
airflow-webserver-1  | ....................
airflow-webserver-1  | ERROR! Maximum number of retries (20) reached.
airflow-webserver-1  | 
airflow-webserver-1  | Last check result:
airflow-webserver-1  | $ airflow db check
airflow-webserver-1  | /home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/configuration.py:812 DeprecationWarning: The sql_alchemy_conn option in [core] has been moved to the sql_alchemy_conn option in [database] - the old setting has been used, but please update your config.
airflow-webserver-1  | /home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/configuration.py:738 DeprecationWarning: The sql_alchemy_conn option in [core] has been moved to the sql_alchemy_conn option in [database] - the old setting has been used, but please update your config.
airflow-webserver-1  | /home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/settings.py:194 DeprecationWarning: The sql_alchemy_conn option in [core] has been moved to the sql_alchemy_conn option in [database] - the old setting has been used, but please update your config.
airflow-webserver-1  | Unable to load the config, contains a configuration error.
airflow-webserver-1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
airflow-webserver-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/logging/config.py", line 563, in configure
airflow-webserver-1  |     handler = self.configure_handler(handlers[name])
airflow-webserver-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/logging/config.py", line 744, in configure_handler
airflow-webserver-1  |     result = factory(**kwargs)
airflow-webserver-1  |   File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/utils/log/file_processor_handler.py", line 50, in __init__
airflow-webserver-1  |     Path(self._get_log_directory()).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
airflow-webserver-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/pathlib.py", line 1288, in mkdir
airflow-webserver-1  |     self._accessor.mkdir(self, mode)
airflow-webserver-1  | PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/opt/airflow/logs/scheduler/2024-03-27'
airflow-webserver-1  | 
airflow-webserver-1  | The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
airflow-webserver-1  | 
airflow-webserver-1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
airflow-webserver-1  |   File "/home/airflow/.local/bin/airflow", line 5, in <module>
airflow-webserver-1  |     from airflow.__main__ import main
airflow-webserver-1  |   File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/__init__.py", line 68, in <module>
airflow-webserver-1  |     settings.initialize()
airflow-webserver-1  |   File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/settings.py", line 554, in initialize
airflow-webserver-1  |     LOGGING_CLASS_PATH = configure_logging()
airflow-webserver-1  |   File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/logging_config.py", line 74, in configure_logging
airflow-webserver-1  |     raise e
airflow-webserver-1  |   File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/logging_config.py", line 69, in configure_logging
airflow-webserver-1  |     dictConfig(logging_config)
airflow-webserver-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/logging/config.py", line 808, in dictConfig
airflow-webserver-1  |     dictConfigClass(config).configure()
airflow-webserver-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/logging/config.py", line 570, in configure
airflow-webserver-1  |     raise ValueError('Unable to configure handler '
airflow-webserver-1  | ValueError: Unable to configure handler 'processor'
airflow-webserver-1  |
```

I tried to change the folder ownership, but I was not succesful.